# Delimited, separated, delimited out, separated out

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> `filename.ext`
>
> A filename extension is typically delimited from the filename itself by a dot.

I'm not sure that the word "delimited" on its own is the best possible option here. Maybe "separated", "separated out", or "delimited out"?

At first glance, "delimited" is good enough. However, when I copy-and-paste some parts of my document to Google Translate and DeepL in accordance to verify the passage in English is translated to my native language correctly, "delimited" fails and "separated out" works fine. And so I make a conclusion that "delimited" is not that precise as I want it.

Which word or collocation is the best to describe the `filename.ext` case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

> A file's extension is separated from its name by a dot.

or, if the file name includes the extension

> A file's extension follows the dot in its name.

Either would be understood.

You could also say

> A dot is the delimiter that separates a file's name from its
> extension.